CSS @import causing race condition with SVG Text dimensions

I have a scenario where I'm dynamically adding elements to the DOM
The elements being added are SVG elements (of various types)
In the case of SVGTextElements, I have layout code which is going to look at the bounding box of the text (getBBox()) to determine where it should be positioned
I am also using external Fonts, imported in CSS using @import

It seems that the font download is completing after the initial page load, so the bounding box of the SVGTextElement is returning incorrect values.
I have tried all sorts of combinations of waiting for load and DOMContentLoaded in the HTML, but these don't appear to encompass CSS downloaded using @import.
I have a working repro of the issue here:
https://codepen.io/jasonpolites/pen/PwYKOyo?editors=1111
If you click the link in the codepen sample, it will load the sample in a new window. This initial "new window" load will display bounding box data that is incorrect. That is, it's (probably) correct for the font data at the time the measurement is taken, but ultimately incorrect based on the imported font. If you then just refresh the page, it will show the correct values.
I could download the font files and serve them locally, but I'm hoping there's a solution which means I don't have to do that.
Are there any tricks to ensure @import statements are fully resolved prior to code executing?

That's a good idea, but I'm not loading the font programmatically. I just have @import statements within another CSS file. It may be that this approach is just flawed, and I may have to switch to loading programmatically, but I'd ideally want to avoid having to hack around what the browser should already be doing :/
Oh I see there is a general onloadingdone event. I will try that

Thanks to Yogi (in the comments) for the pointer.
The fonts property of the document object fires a loadingdone event when all fonts are loaded:
document.fonts.addEventListener("loadingdone", (e) => {
  // Do your thing
});

I found that this event is not triggered if fonts aren't actually used (I may have that wrong), so in my case, I used a "two phase" load:
document.fonts.addEventListener("loadingdone", (e) => {
  // Update elements after fonts loaded
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
  // Render elements that want fonts
});

This is painful, but in my case this is just a hack for Puppeteer tests. In the "real world" I don't need to block on font loading.
